# How to get highest revision only in Eloquent

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a table `pages` like

```
+----+-----------+----------+
| id | slug      | revision |
+----+-----------+----------+
|  1 | foo       |        0 |
|  2 | bar       |        0 |
|  3 | bar       |        1 |
+----+-----------+----------+
```

The slug is unique (not as a key) but among all revisions. Thus, it could be used as a group by statement, if this is helpful.

Technically I have a solution for getting the latest revision only:

```sql
SELECT a.*
FROM `pages` a
  LEFT JOIN `pages` b
      ON a.slug = b.slug AND a.revision < b.revision
WHERE b.revision is NULL
```

In my approach I can use a `select *` to not take care about all the upcoming table cells.

How can I do that more elegant using Laravel Eloquent?
Ideally I implement the logic directly in the `Page` model so that a simple `Page::all()` will give me the highest revisions only.

This is my model:

```
class Page extends Model
{
    use HasFactory, SoftDeletes, Sluggable;

    public function getRouteKeyName()
    {
        return 'slug';
    }

    protected $fillable = [
        'title',
        'slug',
        'revision',
    ];

    public function sluggable(): array
    {
        return [
            'slug' => [
                'source' => 'title',
            ],
        ];
    }

}
``
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```php
Page::select('slug', DB::raw('MAX(revision) as revision'))
    ->groupBy('slug')
    ->get();
```

Comment: It is working, but the downside of that is, that I need to handle all the potential columns in the select statements. It there a way to use `select *` like I did? And how / where do I implement that in my model, so that it is replacing (?) my `all()` and `get()` for every request?

Answer (score 0):

Using `select *` in this query can be archived by setting `strict` to false in `config/database.php`.

Then I needed to add a global scope:

```php
class LatestScope implements Scope
{
    /**
     * Apply the scope to a given Eloquent query builder.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder  $builder
     * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model  $model
     * @return void
     */
    public function apply(Builder $builder, Model $model)
    {
        return $builder->select('*', DB::raw('MAX(revision) as revision'))
            ->groupBy('slug');
    }
}
```

and finally add the global scope to the Model:

```php
class Page extends Model
{
    ...

    /**
     * The "booted" method of the model.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected static function booted()
    {
        static::addGlobalScope(new LatestScope);
    }

}
```